# How to Override Existing SearchDisplayContext Class in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay-7

I want to create custom methods in this existing Class as **SearchDisplayContext** in Liferay 7. This class is belong to **portal-search-web** portlet(OOTB) in liferay dxp.

SearchDisplayContext class is directory path as below link:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/foundation/portal-search/portal-search-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/portal/search/web/internal/display/context/SearchDisplayContext.java

If any one have solution please tell me.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask how to create *custom methods* in an *internal* (see the package) class.

The answer to this question is: You don't.

You might have a problem that is solvable in another way, only we don't know of it.

If you end up really needing to do this, you're looking for a reimplementation of portal-search-web: Make it yours, undeploy Liferay's, deploy your own. And be aware that you're introducing a hard-to-maintain custom modification.

If there's a point for this change, lobby for the introduction of extension points in portal-search-web. You can do so in Liferay's issue tracker and/or on the Liferay forums.

Comment: Hi Olaf,
Thanks for replying.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear earlier. Here's what I am looking for:

1. We are trying to add some functionalities on top of search module
2. We want this feature to be configurable so that we can turn it off/on as per need basis.
3. We were able to add the custom checkbox which will be used for this purpose.
4. Now the issue which we face is that we are unable to save this value in portlet preferences the way SearchContextDisplay does.
5. We were thinking of modifying this but as you mentioned its not a good idea.

Need help or advice for best approach.